# Can someone tell how make user input the element in array and to insert element at the last position?

Tags: c

```
/*ARRAY INSERTION AT THE END*/
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 int main()
 {
    int i,n,insrt;
    char option;
    int array[100];
    printf("\nWHAT IS THE TOTAL NUMBER OF ARRAY YO WANT ?\n");
    scanf(" %d", &n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\nENTER THE NO FOR YOUR ARRAY:\t");
            scanf(" %d", &array[i]);        
        }
    printf("\nYOU HAVE FOLLOWING NO IN THE LIST:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf(" %d==>", array[i]);
    }printf("NULL");
        do
        {
            printf("\nENTER THE VALUE TO BE INSERTED AT THE END:\t");
            scanf(" %d", &insrt);
            for(i=0 ;i<n;i++)
            {

                if (array[i] == 0)
                {
                    array[i] = insrt;
                    printf("\nINSERTION SUCCESSFULL!!\n");
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf("\nTHE ARRAY IS FULL.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf("\nDO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ? TYPE (Y FOR YES AND N FOR NO):\t");
            scanf(" %c", &option);
        }while(option == 'Y' || option == 'y');

        printf("\nYOU HAVE FOLLOWING NO IN THE LIST:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf(" %d==>", array[i]);
        }
        printf("NULL");
        getch();
 }
```

Insertion at the end of the array is not working, tried everything I know but it is still not working and instead of insertion it only prints that array is full.

I know that there is a fault in loop statement but I am unable to fix it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO6Jz.png

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Please do not post an image of text when you actually can add the text into your question.

Comment: You don't initialise `n` before you use it in the array bounds definition => undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Binary_10 It's an Array program as you can see, In this application I want users to input  their own array  elements and after that The application will ask you to enter a number so it  be added at the last position of the array list. But the problem is it is not inserting the number it is only printing array is full every time

Comment: @usr2564301 Sorry sir I am new to stack

Comment: Then you'll be happy to learn you can actually [edit] your question `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st mistake:
You are taking input `n` after defining the array. It should be:

```
scanf(" %d", &n);
int array[n];
```

2nd mistake:

```
            else 
            {
                printf("\nTHE ARRAY IS FULL.\n");
                break;
            }
```

for `i=0`, `a[i] = 432` this is not equal to zero, so it will go to else, and `print "The Array is Full"`.

Just keep track of the number of elements inserted in array, `if no_elem == n-1`, then `print "Array is full"` and `break;`.

Comment: Its int array[100]

Comment: yeah sure, the inputs in array are: [432, 42, 13]. When you are checking for inputting more elements, the first element itself is not equal to zero. This will lead to `else` condition thus breaking the loop.

Comment: so how it is possible to insert any value at last position

Comment: just define an array of large size, keep track of the number of elements inserted in array, if no_elem == n-1, then print "Array is full" and break;. else a[no_elem++] = input_no

Comment: it's my pleasure :) and if you can use `c++` then look for `std::vector`